# selectedValue in knockout is not binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am having a day with knockout. Here is my simplified VM:

```
function UserRecruitingViewModel(apiBaseUrl, userId) {
    var self = this;
    self.orgs = ko.observableArray();
    //ddl org view switcher stuff
    self.orgDdl = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedOrg = ko.observable();
    var DropdownOrg = function (name, orgId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.orgId = orgId;
    };
    //...snip ajax get to pull data...//
}
```

Note I have this line in there:

```
self.selectedOrg = ko.observable();
```

On my page I have this drop down list:

```
<select 
data-bind="options: $root.orgDdl, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: $root.selectedOrg">
</select>
```

For easier reading, the data-bind values:

```
data-bind="
    options: $root.orgDdl, 
    optionsText: 'name', 
    optionsValue: $root.selectedOrg"
```

This is not working. If I have my select element like *without* the optionsValue binding in there it will bind the list with the value I got from the GET request.

I am getting an error in my console saying:

```
Unable to process binding "text: function (){return selectedOrg() }"
Message: selectedOrg is not defined
```

I am confused since I do have the selectedOrg observable set on my VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **selectedOrg** is to get selected option's object, then use like **selectedOption** in my sample.

> ViewModel

```
var optionModel = function(id,name){
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.name = name;
}

var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.options = [
        new optionModel(1,"First"),
        new optionModel(2,"Second")
    ];
   self.selectedOptionId = ko.observable(0);
   self.selectedOption = ko.computed(function(){
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.options, function(item){
            return item.id === self.selectedOptionId();
        });
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

> HTML Bindings

```
<select data-bind="options: options, 
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   optionsValue: 'id', 
                   value: selectedOptionId,
                   optionsCaption:'Choose.....'">
</select>
```

> Above code are for simple options binding with knockout. For this question the model is not well defined, and the reason [**optionsValue**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) you are using is not clear.

[**Here is sample jsfiddle for reference**](http://jsfiddle.net/uU56x/2/)(the sample based on sample option model as your question is not clear)

Comment: Thanks @Goddard. I love the syntax with KO, but sometimes if you aren't paying close attention it will bite you in the ass!

Answer (score 0):

You want just plain `value` in your binding rather than `optionsValue`. `value` specifies what observable gets the result of the selection; `optionsValue` is used if you want `value` to be set to one particular property of an object, rather than the object itself. Assuming you want `selectedOrg()` to contain the entire `DropdownOrg` object that you select, you don't need `optionsValue`.